# Xamarin.forms: Problem with SwipeView in a ListView

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin.Forms application contains a Listview. Currently, the user can see the details of an item in the Listview by selecting this item. I would like to use the swipe function instead of selecting to see the detail of the item. For this, I used the SwipeItem function, as described by Microsoft on the Xamarin.Forms SwipeView page (link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/swipeview). Here's my app's xaml code:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:fab="clr-namespace:Refractored.FabControl;assembly=Refractored.FabControl"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonCircle.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=ButtonCircle.FormsPlugin.Abstractions" 
                 xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:MemoCourses.ViewModels"
                 xmlns:input="clr-namespace:Plugin.InputKit.Shared.Controls;assembly=Plugin.InputKit"
                 xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfNumericTextBox.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfNumericTextBox.XForms"
                 xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:MemoCourses.Helpers"
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 x:Class="MemoCourses.Views.Panier_achatsPage"
                 Title="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_Titre}">

        <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
            <!--<ToolbarItem x:Name ="menuEmpty" Text="Vider le panier"  Order="Secondary" Clicked="menuEmpty_Clicked"/>-->
            <ToolbarItem x:Name ="menuEmptyAll" Text="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_Menu01}"  Order="Secondary" Clicked="menuEmptyAll_Clicked"/>
            <ToolbarItem x:Name ="menuAddFavoris" Text="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_Menu02}"  Order="Secondary" Clicked="menuAddFavoris_Clicked"/>
            <ToolbarItem x:Name ="menuSendMail" Text="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_Menu03}"  Order="Secondary" Clicked="menuSendMail_Clicked"/>
            <ToolbarItem x:Name ="menuViewCard" Text="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_Menu04}"  Order="Secondary" Clicked="menuViewCard_Clicked"/>
            <ToolbarItem x:Name= "menuLockScreen" Text="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_Menu05}" Order="Secondary" Clicked="menuLockScreen_Clicked"/>
            <ToolbarItem x:Name= "menuUnLockScreen" Text="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_Menu06}" Order="Secondary" Clicked="menuUnLockScreen_Clicked"/>
            <ToolbarItem x:Name= "menuBlockModif" Text="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_Menu07}" Order="Secondary" Clicked="menuBlockModif_Clicked"/>
            <ToolbarItem x:Name= "menuUnLockModif" Text="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_Menu08}" Order="Secondary" Clicked="menuUnLockModif_Clicked"/>
        </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

        <Page.Resources>
            <local1:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" />
        </Page.Resources>

        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <Grid AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                      AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,1,1">

                <ListView x:Name="PanierListView"
                        HasUnevenRows="True"
                        IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                        Margin="0,0,0,60"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                        ItemSelected="PanierListView_ItemSelected">

                    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Key}" Margin="0,6,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small" HeightRequest="30" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                    <!--Built in Cells-->
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <ViewCell>

                                <SwipeView>
                                    <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                        <SwipeItems>
                                            <SwipeItem 
                                                Text="Edit"
                                                IconImageSource="edit.png"
                                                BackgroundColor="DarkSeaGreen"
                                                Invoked="OnEditSwipeItem_Invoked" />
                                        </SwipeItems>
                                    </SwipeView.LeftItems>

                                    <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="45*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="3" Grid.Column="0">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageArt, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" 
                                               Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                               WidthRequest="45" 
                                               HeightRequest="45"
                                               VerticalOptions="Start"
                                               Grid.Column="0"/>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                               Margin="10,-4,0,0" FontSize="{Binding NameFontSize}" TextColor="Black" 
                                               FontAttributes="None"
                                               VerticalOptions="Start"
                                               MaxLines="1"
                                               LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                               Grid.Column="0"/>
                                            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="280*" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,-5,0,0" Grid.Column="0">
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding QteArt}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding UniteMesure}" />
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Separator}" />
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Note}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" MaxLines="1"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                                <syncfusion:SfNumericTextBox
                                                    x:Name="totalart"
                                                    Value="{Binding TotalArt}" 
                                                    IsVisible="{Binding TotalVisible}"
                                                    MaximumNumberDecimalDigits="2"
                                                    FormatString="0.00 €"
                                                    Margin="0,-15,0,0"
                                                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                                                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                                    FontSize="Small"
                                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                                />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <input:CheckBox Grid.Column="1"
                                                    x:Name="chkBoxPanierOut"
                                                    IsChecked="{Binding IsChk, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                    Type="Check"
                                                    Color="Green"
                                                    BoxSizeRequest="28"
                                                    BindingContext="{Binding .}"
                                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                    Margin="10,0,20,0"
                                                    CheckChanged="chkBoxPanierOut_CheckChanged">
                                    </input:CheckBox>
                                </Grid>

                                </SwipeView>

                            </ViewCell>

                            
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    <ListView.Footer>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text=" "/>
                            <Label Text=" "/>
                            <Label Text=" "/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ListView.Footer>
                </ListView>

                

                <Grid HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <Image x:Name="ImgListEmpty" 
                               Opacity="0.7" 
                               IsVisible="false" 
                               Aspect="Fill"
                               Source="Avertissement_7.png"/>
                    <Label x:Name="AdvertListEmpty1"
                               IsVisible="false"
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               TextColor="White"
                               FontAttributes="Italic"
                               Text="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_Avert01}"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Margin=" 0,-30,0,0"/>
                    <Label x:Name="AdvertListEmpty2"
                               IsVisible="false"
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               TextColor="White"
                               FontAttributes="Italic"
                               Text="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_Avert02}"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Margin=" 0,30,0,0"/>
                    <Image x:Name="ImgCartFull" 
                               Opacity="0.7" 
                               IsVisible="false" 
                               Aspect="Fill"
                               Source="Avertissement_6.png"/>
                    <Label x:Name="AdvertCartFull"
                               IsVisible="false"
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               TextColor="White"
                               FontAttributes="Italic"
                               Text="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_Avert03}"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label x:Name="TextFavEmptyL1"
                               IsVisible="false"
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               TextColor="White"
                               FontAttributes="Italic"
                               Text="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_Avert04}"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Margin=" 0,-30,0,0"/>
                    <Label x:Name="TextFavEmptyL2"
                               IsVisible="false"
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               TextColor="White"
                               FontAttributes="Italic"
                               Text="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_Avert05}"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               Margin=" 0,30,0,0"/>
                </Grid>

                <local:CircleButton 
                    FontIcon="Material"
                    Icon="add" 
                    FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" 
                    HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60"
                    CornerRadius="30"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    VerticalOptions="End"
                    Margin="0,0,20,40"
                    Clicked="FabBtnAdd_clicked"
                    BackgroundColor="#5E91FF"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, AutoSize, AutoSize">
                </local:CircleButton>

                <local:CircleButton x:Name="CircleBtnLock"
                    FontIcon="Material"
                    Icon="md-lock" 
                    FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" 
                    HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"
                    CornerRadius="30"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    VerticalOptions="End"
                    Margin="0,0,110,55"
                    Clicked="CircleBtnLock_clicked"
                    BackgroundColor="IndianRed"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, AutoSize, AutoSize">
                </local:CircleButton>

                <local:CircleButton x:Name="CircleBtnStopModif"
                    FontIcon="Material"
                    Icon="md-edit" 
                    FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" 
                    HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"
                    CornerRadius="30"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    VerticalOptions="End"
                    Margin="0,0,165,55"
                    Clicked="CircleBtnStopModif_Clicked"
                    BackgroundColor="IndianRed"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, AutoSize, AutoSize">
                </local:CircleButton>

                <local:CircleButton x:Name="CircleBtnUnLockModif"
                        FontIcon="Material"
                        Icon="md-edit" 
                        IsVisible="false"
                        FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" 
                        HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"
                        CornerRadius="30"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        VerticalOptions="End"
                        Margin="0,0,165,55"
                        Clicked="CircleBtnUnLockModif_Clicked"
                        BackgroundColor="YellowGreen"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, AutoSize, AutoSize">
                </local:CircleButton>

                <Label  Text="{helpers:Translate Panier_achatsPage_L01}" 
                            x:Name="totaltxt"
                            Margin="75,0,0,20"
                            VerticalOptions="End"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, AutoSize, AutoSize"
                            FontSize="Medium" 
                            FontAttributes="Bold" 
                            IsVisible="true"/>

                <Label  x:Name="totalAchats"
                            Text="" 
                            Margin="145,0,0,20"
                            VerticalOptions="End"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, AutoSize, AutoSize"
                            FontSize="Medium" 
                            FontAttributes="Bold" 
                            IsVisible="true"/>

                <Label  Text=" €"
                            x:Name="devisetxt"
                            Margin="210,0,0,20"
                            VerticalOptions="End"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, AutoSize, AutoSize"
                            FontSize="Medium" 
                            FontAttributes="Bold" 
                            IsVisible="true"/>


                <Grid HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <Image x:Name="fondAI" 
                               Opacity="0.8" 
                               IsVisible="true" 
                               Aspect="Fill"
                               Source="FondProgressRing.png"/>
                    <local:CircleButton x:Name="CircleBtnUnLock"
                        FontIcon="Material"
                        Icon="md-lock-open" 
                        IsVisible="true"
                        FontSize="Medium" TextColor="White" 
                        HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"
                        CornerRadius="30"
                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                        VerticalOptions="End"
                        Margin="0,0,110,55"
                        Clicked="CircleBtnUnLock_clicked"
                        BackgroundColor="Green"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, AutoSize, AutoSize">
                    </local:CircleButton>

                    

                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </AbsoluteLayout>


    </ContentPage>
```

This is the codebehind of the action FabBtnAdd_clicked

```
private async void FabBtnAdd_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DB_ListeAchatsList = dblisteachats.GetAllListeAchats();
        var listeachats = DB_ListeAchatsList.Where(x => x.NomListe == App.currentListeAchat).FirstOrDefault();
        //
        var artpanierpage = new ArtPanierPage();
        artpanierpage.BindingContext = listeachats;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(artpanierpage);
    }
```

Unfortunately, I'm having a problem running it. When the Listview is empty, the XAML page opens, and I can add items by tapping the + button. But if there is an item, the program crashes without an error message. There's just this in the exit window:

> [libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x4 in tid 12730 (oft.memocourses), pid 12730 (oft.memocourses)

I found examples given by other developers on the site and overall, it looks like my code. I do not understand what is happening. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post you xaml.cs code as well. And when exactly the crash happen, on loading, on click the item, on swipe or some other actions? If you remove the swipe view part does the listview work?

Comment: The crash occurs as soon as the page is opened (on loading), when there is 1 item in the Listview. And if I remove the code corresponding to the SwipeItem, everything works normally. I replaced the XAML code with the entire page.

Comment: May I ask how you implement ```FabBtnAdd_clicked``` event handler.  If possible, you could also share the relevant code in code behind and viewmodel.

Comment: @Liqun: I edited my question to add the codebehind of the action FabBtnAdd_clicked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could try set a breakpoint in ```FabBtnAdd_clicked``` and find out which line cause this error.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this suggestion.  I'll give you the results in a few hours.

Comment: When I put a breakpoint on the FabBtnAdd_clicked action, everything runs fine, I go to the artpanierpage and I choose the items to add in the listview. When I return to the start page (I put a breakpoint on OnAppearing()), the application crashes with the debugger message "no compatible code is running on the thread".

Comment: Is ```Panier_achatsPage``` the start page? Sorry, I am a little confused.  In ```Panier_achatsPage``` , there is a ```PanierListView```. And when you press the add button, it will navigation to a new ```ArtPanierPage```. But I didn't find how you add the item in ```PanierListView```  in ```Panier_achatsPage```. Did you do that in the new ```ArtPanierPage```?

Comment: The `Panier_achatsPage` is not the start page. Adding an item to the listview is done by returning to the `Panier_achatsPage` : in `OnAppearing()`, the SQLite database is reread, this item having been added to the `ArtPanierPage`. I hope I explained the process well.

Comment: What's the version of MAUI do you use? Here is a known issue : [Android "No compatible code running on the thread" and crash after hit continue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16189). You may try: 1. Delete obj and bins and restart vs; 2. update the visual studio to the new version.

Comment: I deleted the bin and obj folders, uninstalled the app from my emulator and relaunched the app. I have the same problem: app crash as soon as I add a product to the listview. I can't find any indication of MAUI's version. Where can I find the version of this component? I am using VS 2022 v 17.6.5

Answer (score 0):

I updated Xamarin.Essentials to version 1.7.0 and Xamarin.Forms to version 5.0.0.2196, and since then the app no longer crashes, and the Swipe works correctly (except for the SwipeView command which no longer accepts the Threshold parameter). The update has created other problems, but since it does not bring back to the Swipeview, so I will ask a new question. Thank you.